# Including jquery breaks tabs, not including jquery prevents my program from executing

Tags: jquery, tabs

I implemented some code with jquery that's working well independently. I would like to make the content rendered by the code one of the tabs using EasyTabs. (Or any tab plugin, stereotab has the same problem).

My problem is that as soon as I include jquery the tabs all break and all the information from each tab is jut rendered on the current tab.

For instance, you can download the demo that easytabs uses here: http://jspkg.com/packages/easytabs

If you open demo.html and include the following line:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The tabs break and render all the content on one page.

What gives?

Comment: I don't know if the case but the demo uses 1.7.1.

Comment: This seems to be the problem. The demo uses an older version of jquery which breaks my code. Does anyone know of a tabs demo that uses jquery 1.7.2?

Comment: You can either patch the script or reach out to the original script writer. Maybe buy him a beer or smth. :)